# OLS Regression: Predicting to the certain total

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

I have a simple dataset

```
Rooms   Price(in March)

Single   20

Balcony  50 

Triple   100

Couple   75

Family   150
```

Now, I can predict the values and set the values in the new column `Price(in September)` using OLS approach. But I want the prediction to follow the case that the total price of all the rooms be exactly 500. Any idea to bring the case that the sum of the predicted values always becomes 500?

Comment: From what I know about this you can´t have linear correlation between your independent variables. If you make a linear regression where all variables must sum up to 500 you will have a problem and won´t have consistent estimators

Comment: any approach for this prediction?

Comment: You should include other variables in your model, otherwise your predictions won´t have significance. Having correlation in your independent variables will bring questionable p-values. I strongly suggest you to include other variables in your model. But you can also try to standarize your variables by subtracting the mean. Also, you can try using another model other than OLS

Comment: I think I am not getting the problem yet, can you elaborate a bit more? From what I understand you try to predict the price in September but actually you want that prediction to be 500?

Comment: @coffeinjunky i want to predict the price but the total of all of the predictions should be 500

Comment: There are models for predicting probabilities of multiple outcomes, such as multinomial logistic regression. The `summing up to one` is built into these models as they are meant to model probabilities. If you standardize your prices by their respective sums, maybe these models would help you. You would then get small fractions that you would simply need to multiply with 500. Having said that, the application to prices is somewhat unconventional. Would be good to understand the context better.

Comment: FYIW: I am voting to move this question to Cross Validated.